# Remove double quotes from a string in velocity template

Tags: java, html, velocity

The input is : `var={cost=7022.61, marker=down, month=AUGUST, totalCost=17147.52}`

The code is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ESTIMATE FOR $var.month $var.cost</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Spent Last Month $var.totalCost</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**output** : ESTIMATE FOR "AUGUST" "7022.61"
Spent Last Month "17147.52"

**Expected output** : ESTIMATE FOR AUGUST 7022.61
Spent Last Month 17147.52

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

i solved in this way (velocity 1.7)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ESTIMATE FOR $!{var.month.replace('"',"")} $!{var.cost.replace('"',"")}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Spent Last Month $!{var.totalCost.replace('"',"")}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I hope I've given you all the answers about your question.

Comment: i replaced $var.month with $!{var.month.replace('"',"")} but it didnt print anything this time now.

Comment: If var.month is null don't print anything because there is '!'

Comment: any other solution this wont work for me because i am expecting double quote to be a part of my value